# Nginx returns 404 for some sub domains but not for others

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404

So I'm trying to setup 5 websites, all on the same domain just with diffrent subdomain, etc www. and cdn.
but www. works fine as it should
tho cdn. does not, It got the same files I just copyed them over, all permissions are the same for the folders.
I have each sub domain in their own files etc wwwmydomaincom and cdnmydomaincom and the config is the same, only diffrence is server_name. the file that works got www.mydomain.com the rest got somesubdomain.mydomain.com and they throw 404.

I use Nginx on ubuntu server 16.04.1.

Added

```
location / {
  try_files $uri.html;
}
```

and the sub domains displays the html pages fine (now their config isent like the one that works)
But.. every asset, css, js, images or other things get 404 so it's a pure html page.

The config under is the exact same config as www.mydomain.com but changed to fit cdn.mydomain.com

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name cdn.domain.com;
  location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
     default_type "text/plain";
     root /storage/webserver/certbot;
  }

  #Forces all other requests to HTTPS
  location / {
     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name cdn.domain.com;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/cdn.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/cdn.domain.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA512:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AESGCM:DH+AES256:RSA+AESGCM:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS;
  ssl_session_cache shared:TLS:2m;
  # OCSP stapling
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  resolver 8.8.8.8;
  # Set HSTS to 365 days
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains';
  root /storage/webserver/cdn.domain.com;
  index index.html index.php;
  location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^ $uri.php last;
    try_files $uri =404;
  }
  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    try_files $uri =404;
  }
  rewrite ^(/.*)\.html(\?.*)?$ $1$2 permanent;
  #rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
  error_page 404 /404.php;
  error_page 500 503 502 504 /error/40x.php;
  location =/error/40x.html {
    internal;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahem, this is why I want to learn this kind of stuff.

You obviosly need to make it look for the files.

so if anyone enters this litte situation, Don't forget to make it look in the root folder.

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html @rewrite;
}
```